# Installing Spring Cloud CLI - which version with Spring boot 2.4.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I want to install Spring Cloud CLI, but am not clear which version to use.

This Spring cloud page https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud  shows the compatible versions of Spring Cloud with Boot. For example

| Release Train | Boot Version |
| --- | --- |
| 2020.0.x aka Ilford | 2.4.x |
| Hoxton | 2.2.x, 2.3.x (Starting with SR5) |

I have Spring boot 2.4.5 installed. This implies I should use Spring cloud version 2020.0.x

If I check https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud/ I do not see a version 2020.0.x

If I use
spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2020.0.1
I get an error "could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:jar:2020.0.1 "

If I use

$ spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.2.0.RELEASE

it appears to install correctly, however I get errors when I try to run commands like

$ spring cloud eureka.

My question is what version of cloud should I install with spring boot v 2.4.5 ?

Answer (score 1):

`2020.0.x` is the version of the Spring Cloud release train, not of the single modules itself. The release train version can be used, if you use the Spring Cloud BOM to include the dependencies, as described here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud.

This would look similar to this then:

```
<properties>
  <spring.cloud-version>Hoxton.SR8</spring.cloud-version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
       <version>${spring.cloud-version}</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

If you only want to use single modules, then you need to find out, which versions belong to the release train, by either looking in the respective `spring-cloud-dependencies` POM (https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/2020.0.2/), or in the release notes, which also contain the module versions: https://spring.io/blog/2021/03/18/spring-cloud-2020-0-2-aka-ilford-is-available

So in your case, the proper version for `spring-cloud-cli` would be `3.0.2`.